# Font differences in .NET 8

Tags: maui

When I switched my App from .NET 7 to the new .NET 8 I recognized that the Font doesn’t look as smooth as it does on .NET 7. I don’t know what it is and what I should change that it looks the same.

I even can’t say exactly what it is, maybe it looks as if it is Bold - at least it appears firmer.

This is not only on my Labels but also Entry’s.

I did not change anything in my Styles.xml when I migrated to .NET 8. just set the .csproj to net8.0

As I don’t want to change all the Fonts separately and apply corresponding Styles to all my UI elements is there a way I can set them all back to how it looked like in .NET 7?

**.NET 7:**

[image]

**.NET 8:**

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: drawing text is handled by the OS, I would be surprised if the .NET version had any impact on that

Comment: If you could, perhaps take a screengrab of the before and after, and zoom in to the pixels to see if there are antialiasing, scaling differences. Or, even if there's a bluriness vs sharpness.

Comment: It seems to be bigger and feels like it is bold now. But just to make sure nothing is in my font settings like that for the Label and Entrys. Is there a setting I can make?

Comment: Now I got it - it's due to something I already defined as Bug. In previous versions resources defined inside a Grid worked additive/overwriting. Now, they replace the entire default style and not only what we defined in the resource. In case of my Labels/Entrys I have a Grid.Resource like `<Grid.Resources>     <Style TargetType="Label">         <Setter Property="VerticalTextAlignment" Value="Center"/>     </Style> </Grid.Resources>` that previously took the global Label Style (defined in Styles.xml) and overwrote the `VerticalTextAlignment`. This replaces the default Label-Styles entirely

Comment: Corresponding Bug: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/19882. At least I consider it as a Bug. But, I do not know if this is a defined feature and wanted behavior change. Previously, in `Grid.Resources` you could just overwrite one of the properties like the `VerticalTextAlignment`. The other properties derived from the global `Styles.xml` stayed the same and did not get overwritten. Now, adding the `VerticalTextAlignment` in the `Grid.Resources` the entire global Style definition for Labels from global Styles.xml is overwritten and so we do not see the original/global Font definitions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @OXO provided, this is a known issue. Here is the link about the issue [[Grid] Using Grid.Resources e.g. for Buttons overwrites default Button styles](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/19882).

This issue may cause the style in the Style.xml be overwritten. When adding the style elements in `Grid.Resources`, the entire global style definition in the global Styles.xml will be overwritten.

Now it has been put into the backlog. You can follow this issue up and wait for the fix.

Comment: Yes, that’s the corresponding Bug I wrote